# ngOnInit não salva valor da variável retornada por uma função

Tags: angular

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
 getCampos(id: String) {
console.log('id em getCampos:', id);
this.es.getDocument(EditSiteComponent.INDEX, EditSiteComponent.TYPE, id).then(
  response => {
    this.campos = response[0]._source;
    console.log('Campos em getCampos',this.campos);
    return this.campos;
  }, error => {
    console.log('Erro', error);
  });
```

}

Tenho certeza que a mesma funciona, pois os `console.log` dela apresentam o valor esperado.

Agora quando pego o valor dela no ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Edit site component ----------');
    this.fields = this.getCampos(this._id);
     console.log(this.fields);
  }
```

O valor de `fields` fica como `undefined` por algum motivo.
A ideia é pegar esse objeto e acessar seus atributos num formulário do angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o JavaScript, TypeScript nesse caso eh *assincrono*. Então na função abaixo:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('Edit site component ----------');
  this.fields = this.getCampos(this._id);
  console.log(this.fields);
}
```

A todas as linhas são processadas em sequência, a terceira linha, `console.log(this.fields)` é executada antes que o valor de `this.fields` esteja pronto para ser exibido.

Você precisa estruturar seu código de forma que você garanta que um determinado valor, só é chamado após estar carregado.

Observe isso acontendo na outra função, no trecho abaixo:

```
this.es.getDocument(EditSiteComponent.INDEX, EditSiteComponent.TYPE, id).then(
  response => {
    this.campos = response[0]._source;
    console.log('Campos em getCampos',this.campos);
    return this.campos;
  }, error => {
    console.log('Erro', error);
  });
```

O `then`, chama uma função de `callback` apenas quando a sua funçao `this.es.getDocument` está concluída, aqui é uma chamada *sincronizada*. Por isso você tem os valores impressos corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso formBuilder para pegar os valores e trabalhar num form.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Formularios } from '../../../interface/formularios';
import { FormulariosService } from '../../../services/formularios.service';
import { Modulos } from '../../../interface/modulos';
import { ModulosService } from '../../../services/modulos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modulos-shortcut',
  templateUrl: './modulos-shortcut.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modulos-shortcut.component.css']
})
export class ModulosShortcutComponent implements OnInit {

  modulos: Modulos[];
  modulo: Modulos;
  formularios: Formularios;
  formulariosForm: FormGroup;
  currentAction: string;
  pageTitle: string;
  idModulo: any;

  constructor(private formulariosService: FormulariosService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private modulosService: ModulosService,
              private elementRef: ElementRef,
              private location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setCurrentAction();

    this.formulariosForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id_formulario: [null],
      nome_formulario: [null, Validators.required],
      descricao: [null, Validators.required],
      id_modulo: [null, Validators.required],
      url: [null, Validators.required]
    });

    this.getListModulos();
    this.loadPage();
  }
  private setCurrentAction() {

    this.currentAction = 'new';
    this.pageTitle = 'Criar Formulario';

  }

  private loadPage() {
    this.idModulo = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.modulosService.getId(this.idModulo).subscribe(
      (modulo: Modulos) => {this.updateForm(modulo); }
    );
  }

  private updateForm(item) {
    console.log(item[0]);
    this.formulariosForm.patchValue({
      id_modulo: item[0].id_modulo
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {

    if(this.formulariosForm.valid) {
      this.formulariosService.create(this.formulariosForm.value).subscribe(
        (response) => {console.log(response); this.router.navigate(['modulos']);},
        (error) => {console.log(error); }
      );
    } else {
      this.validatedForm(this.formulariosForm);
    }
  }

  validatedForm(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(
      campo => {console.log(campo);
      const controle = formGroup.get(campo);
      controle.markAsTouched(); }
      );
  }

  goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }

  getListModulos() {
    this.modulosService.getList().subscribe(
      (modulos: Modulos[]) => {this.modulos = modulos; }
    );
  }
}
```

No html fica assim:

```html
<a (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-warning btn-md m-3">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span> &lt;&lt; Voltar
</a>
<div class="m-5">
    <h3>{{ pageTitle }} </h3>

</div>
<form class="m-5" [formGroup]="formulariosForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="nome_formulario">Nome do Formulário</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_formulario" formControlName="nome_formulario">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!formulariosForm.controls['nome_formulario'].valid && formulariosForm.controls['nome_formulario'].touched"> Nome do Formulário não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descricao" formControlName="descricao">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!formulariosForm.controls['descricao'].valid && formulariosForm.controls['descricao'].touched"> A Descrição não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="id_modulo">ID Módulo</label>
      <select name="modulo" id="modulo" class="form-control modulo" formControlName="id_modulo" [attr.disabled]="true">
        <option value="{{ m.id_modulo }}" *ngFor="let m of modulos" >{{m.nome_modulo }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="url">URL</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" formControlName="url">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!formulariosForm.controls['url'].valid && formulariosForm.controls['url'].touched"> A URL não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <button [disabled]="!formulariosForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg float-right mt-3 mb-4">Salvar</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: irei dar uma olhada, obrigado